# Detect J2EE container stop event while a servlet's doGet() is still running

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, listener, containers

I am trying to detect an application stop event (in Websphere 8.0) to invoke a servlet's static method. I wonder if there's a straightforward way to find out if the application has been ordered to stop.

This is the scenario:

1. I have one servlet, `WorkerServlet`, running a loop like this
   `while(!forceStop){...}` in its doGet(). While the application is
   up, this loop is continuously running.
2. When the container stops the
   application (because of any event such as republish, stop, restart
   the application/server) I would like to invoke the static method `WorkerServlet.forceStop(){forceStop = true;}`.

This way, WorkerServlet's loop would finish and the servlet could be destroyed by the container right away. The current behaviour is that the container waits for 60 seconds before forcing the destroy which is unacceptable during development time.

I have tried different approaches but none of them works

1. A **ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed()**. Not called until all servlets are destroyed
2. A **Spring ApplicationListener** to detect when de application context is going to    be destroyed. Not called until all servlets are destroyed.
3. **Another servlet with a destroy() method** that invokes `WorkerServlet.forceStop()`. The container doesn't destroy() this servlet since there's another one running a request.

So, is there any other way to detect the container's app shutdown event so that I can invoke that static method?

Comment: Does `contextDestroyed()` method getting called only after all the servlets are destroyed make any difference to you application flow ?

Comment: Yes... I tried to use ``ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed()`` to invoke ``WorkerServlet.forceDestroy()``. But, since it's not called until all servlets are destroyed it's useless...

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what are you trying to achieve with that infinite loop ?

Comment: The loop generates live performance metrics. It's part of a framework so there's no way of doing it in a different way.

Comment: If its part of a framework and this is just unacceptable during dev phase, why not just turn off the Servlet altogether?

Comment: Although we turned off the servlet in our local environment, the deployment team wouldn't allow us to have such a lazy app that hangs for 60 secs until republishing. Anyway I got a solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workaround I found was to use a startup bean. Fortunately Webshpere's EJB container is stopped before the servlet container:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class WorkerServletStopper {

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy(){
        WorkerServlet.forceStop();
    }
}
```